# Error in regression model for an SDM - get "Error in rep(1, nrow(pres_trainM2)) : invalid 'times' argument

Tags: r

Basically, I'm trying to run a regression analysis as part of a species distribution study.

```
#Regression model
backg_trainM2 <- SpatialPoints(backg_trainM2, 
       proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))

trainM2 <- bind(pres_trainM2, backg_trainM2)
backg_trainM2 <- backg[groupM2 != 1, ]

pb_trainM2 <- c(rep(1, nrow(pres_trainM2)), rep(0,     nrow(backg_trainM2)))
```

It works perfectly until I get to pb_trainM2 - then it gives me the error:

> ```
> Error in rep(1, nrow(pres_trainM2)) : invalid 'times' argument
> ```

What could be causing this? I've seen the error in other questions here, but the solutions they used didn;t work for me.

Apologies if this is a rookie question, I'm still very new to R.

EDIT:

This is Prestrain, it's an S4 spatial points object (with 2802 coordinates):

```
  pres_trainM2
class       : SpatialPoints
```

features    : 2802 
extent      : -9.360213, 26.46285, 36.07, 61.2114  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0

Whilst Backg_trainM2 is a 2 column object thingie, 800 rows long. Here are the 1st 20 rows:

```
> backg_trainM2
              x        y
  [1,]  34.62083333 61.26250
  [2,]  -5.31250000 50.10417
  [3,]  19.72083333 49.52917
  [4,]  -4.27083333 58.23750
  [5,]  -2.66250000 38.17917
  [6,]  -7.64583333 54.01250
  [7,]  15.18750000 56.64583
  [8,]  -5.37916667 39.80417
  [9,]  35.10416667 56.70417
 [10,]  29.77083333 68.18750
 [11,]  11.97083333 32.27083
 [12,]   9.12083333 35.15417
 [13,]  17.97916667 46.40417
 [14,]   0.62916667 49.19583
 [15,]   6.12916667 36.40417
 [16,]   2.77916667 50.11250
 [17,]  -4.87083333 33.52917
 [18,]  25.64583333 61.60417
 [19,]  12.04583333 45.35417
 [20,]  34.26250000 40.97083
```

Thanks so much for all your time and patience so far.

Comment: please share your data so the code can be reproducible.

Comment: I used the bioclim data set to make environmental variables, and I'll try to add my species data momentarily. As soon as I figure out how to

Comment: I can't figure out how to upload the full data here. So as an explanation, the data set includes column for species name, then one each for longitude and latitude

Comment: if you copy and paste the output from `dput(yourdata)` you can share it in the post, if the data is large you can share just a sample that is relevant to your question

Comment: Thanks so much for your help (-:   I will indeed just share a sample, backgtrain has 800 rows and Pres_train has 2802 features



 backg_trainM2
                  x        y
  [1,]  34.62083333 61.26250
  [2,]  -5.31250000 50.10417
  [3,]  19.72083333 49.52917
  [4,]  -4.27083333 58.23750
  [5,]  -2.66250000 38.17917
  [6,]  -7.64583333 54.01250
  [7,]  15.18750000 56.64583
  [8,]  -5.37916667 39.80417
  [9,]  35.10416667 56.70417
 [10,]  29.77083333 68.18750

Comment: no problem, users will find it more helpful for you to post the data in the question instead of the comments. Also, I would format your code to improve readability